# Integrating Driverless AI with Anylogic Simulation, MOJO Pipeline error

Tags: anylogic, driverless-ai

I am trying to integrate Driverless AI in my Anylogic Simulation project, but am unable to make the mojo pipeline work. I have placed the license.sig file in the same directory as mojo pipeline. The license.sig file I am using has been created using a text file of the license key, hope that is not a problem here. The error I am getting is "Model cannot be resolved"

Below is the code I used to run MOJO:

```
MojoFrameBuilder fb = stayDurationModel.getInputFrameBuilder();
MojoRowBuilder rb = fb.getMojoRowBuilder();
rb.setString("ORG", ORG);
rb.setString("Org_Product", Org_Product);
rb.setString("Org_Region", Org_Region);
rb.setDate("Due Date", new java.sql.Date(Due_Date.getTime()));
rb.setString("Customer Name", Customer_Name);
rb.setDouble("Invoice Amount", Invoice_Amount);
rb.setString("Bank Account Name", Bank_Account_Name);

fb.addRow(rb);

MojoFrame iframe = fb.toMojoFrame();
MojoFrame oframe = DSOModel.transform(iframe);

// Extract output from frame:
String[] outputArray = oframe.getColumn(0).getDataAsStrings();
double DSO = Double.valueOf(outputArray[0]);

lblPatientTxt.setText("Invoice(\n ORG: " + ORG + ",\n Org_Product: " + 
Org_Product + ",\n Due Date " + Due_Date + ",\n Invoice Amount" + 
Invoice_Amount + ",\n Customer Name " + Customer_Name + ",\n Bank Account 
Name" 
+ Bank_Account_Name  + ")");
lblBedDays.setText("DSO" + DSO + " days");
stayDurationDS.add(DSO);

return DSO;
```

Have attached the console error logs and the code. Thanks in advance!

[Console Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSJPJ.png)

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for running the mojo?

Comment: Hi Neema, thank you very much for your response. I have edited the post with the code. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what is the cause. Your code doesn't show how the pipeline.mojo is loaded. I would recommend you first try using the `run_example.sh` and make sure you can score with `example.csv` [link](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/scoring-mojo-scoring-pipeline.html). Then modify it to match your code to see where is the discrepancy.